# Audio Infinito En Javascript

Tags: javascript, ajax, web, signalr

Tengo un JavaScript que corre un audio, cabe mencionar que uso ASP.NET y usa SignalR, la cuestión aquí es que cuando carga la pantalla, en ocasiones el sonido entra en un ciclo y se reproduce hasta el infinito les dejo el código a continuación

```
$(function () {
    // Declare a proxy to reference the hub.
    var notifications = $.connection.MyHub;

    //debugger;
    // Create a function that the hub can call to broadcast messages.
    notifications.client.updateMessages = function () {
        getAllMessages()

    };
    // Start the connection.
    $.connection.hub.start().done(function () {
        //alert("connection started")
        //notifications.onconn();
        getAllMessages();
    }).fail(function (e) {
        alert(e);
    });
});
//var colorBk = "", llamadaBk;
function getAllMessages()
{
    var tbl = $('#messagesTable');
    var today = new Date();
    var dd = today.getDate();
    var mm = today.getMonth() + 1;
    var yyyy = today.getFullYear();
    var audio = document.getElementById('audio');

    if (dd < 10) {
        dd = '0' + dd
    }

    if (mm < 10) {
        mm = '0' + mm
    }


    $.ajax({
        url: '/Home/GetMessages',
        contentType: 'application/html ; charset:utf-8',
        type: 'GET',
        dataType: 'html'
    }).success(function (result) {
        var a2 = JSON.parse(result);
        tbl.empty();
        $.each(a2, function (key, value) {


            //alert(colorBk);
            //$("#date").html("<b>" + dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy + "</b>");
            //document.getElementById("date").innerHTML = dd + '/' + mm + '/' + yyyy;
            $("#descripcionANDON").html("<b>" + value.status + "</b>");
            document.bgColor = value.color;
            //$("#tab").html("<audio id='audio' controls><source type='audio/wav' src=''></audio>");
            tbl.append('<tr>' + '<td>' + value.maquina + '</td>' + '</tr>');

            if (value.color == 'Red') {
                audio.setAttribute('src', '/sounds/InicioParo.wav');
            } else if (value.color == 'Yellow') {
                audio.setAttribute('src', '/sounds/GM140A MMTO.mp3');
            } else {
                audio.setAttribute('src', '/sounds/FinParo.wav');

                if (value.status == '') {
                    $("#descripcionANDON").html("<b> Operación Iniciada </b>");
                    document.bgColor = "Green"
                }
            }
             audio = document.getElementById('audio');
     audio.play();               
        });
        //alert(audio.paused);



        //if (audio.duration > 0 && !audio.paused) {

        //} else {


        //}

    })

}
```

Comment: Hola, bienvenid@ a StackOverflow en español, te sugiero hacer el [tour] para que tengas una mejor idea sobre el funcionamiento de la pagina y puedas dar a conocer tu pregunta de mejor manera. Saludos.

Comment: Sería bueno si pudieras añadir algo más de información para entender mejor el problema: ¿A qué te refieres con que se reproduce hasta el infinito? ¿Cuál es el comportamiento esperado? ¿Cuál es el html del audio? Aparte, hay una cosa rara en el código, utilizas la variable `audio` antes de definirla (o la vuelves a redefinir después de usarla, estoy en móvil y el código lo veo regular).